# Android - destroying service on calling stopService

Tags: android, service, ondestroy

I have a background service that I start and stop using `startService()` and `stopService()` when the respective buttons are pressed on the UI ("connect" and "disconnect" respectively).

I perform a lot of clean up operations when the service is stopped, and I put those in the service's `onDestroy()` assuming that would be called whenever `stopService()` is called. However, I observed that `onDestroy()` is not called immediately when `stopService()` is called. It might be called in some time, or after a *very* long time.

What can I do to ensure those clean-up operations are performed as soon as `stopService()` is called (which is triggered whenever someone clicks the "disconnect" button) ? Do I *have* to go for the `bindService()` approach, or is there some other way ?

**Note:** The service is running in a process of its own, within the same application.

Comment: the simplest solution: stopService(); cleanUpStuff();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Once requested to stop with [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()) or [stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)), the system
>   destroys the service as soon as possible.
>
> However, if your service handles multiple requests to [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int))
>   concurrently, then you shouldn't stop the service when you're done
>   processing a start request, because you might have since received a
>   new start request (stopping at the end of the first request would
>   terminate the second one). To avoid this problem, you can use
>   stopSelf(int) to ensure that your request to stop the service is
>   always based on the most recent start request. That is, when you call
>   stopSelf(int), you pass the ID of the start request (the startId
>   delivered to onStartCommand()) to which your stop request corresponds.
>   Then if the service received a new start request before you were able
>   to call stopSelf(int), then the ID will not match and the service will
>   not stop.

Since `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` kill the service as soon as possible there might be other factors that are keeping it alive (since you say it sometimes takes a long time for `onDestory()` to be called that seems to be the case). You might want to monitor your service for incoming activity that might be preventing the service from shutting down in a timely manner.

Comment: I read on other answers on SO and a couple other places that the service isn't killed as soon as stopService is called. Is that true ? Also, there's nothing else connecting to my service or keeping it alive.

Comment: It's not killed as soon as you call `stopService` - it's destroyed *as soon as possible*.  Basically that is Android's way of telling you that you have no guarantee that the service will stop at a certain time - just when the OS gets around to it.  Services don't share the same lifecycle like with normal apps and they run in a different process so calling `stopService` is really just putting in a request to kill your service but you have to wait in line for the OS to finish whatever else it was working on before it will get around to finally killing it.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `finish()` in `stopService()`. This will invoke `onDestroy()`